# Are there any pitfalls to setting higher values on a XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object, specifically MaxStringContentLength and MaxArrayLength?

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

Of special note, this is for the `ReaderQuotas` property on a `BasicHttpBinding` object. Specifically, might I have a (very) few situations where my current value of 163,840,000 (magic undocumented value from previous dev, not sure of the source) isn't sufficient. However, I'm weary about raising this value even more for seemingly few edge cases, though they may be important in production (a paying client's) environment.

What I would like to know is, are there any known or hidden pitfalls in using higher values, other than explicitly allowing a large amount of data get serialized and sent down the pipe (this is for a WCF endpoint)? And if there are pitfalls, what might they be, and what would be affected.

Comment: Of note, I am considering using `XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max` as the value, rather than simply try and conjure up a new magic value which would hold me over until the next time the limit becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a project and didn't run into any issue except that we also had to increase or binding timeouts of the server and client.  Latter however we changed the program to give us bounded data retuns as the fix was indicative of a poor design choice on my part.